# Can I define a site as a category endowed with a pretopology instead of a topology?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

If $K$ is a pretopology on a category $\mathcal{C}$ and $J$ the topology it induces, are the Grothendieck toposes $\text{Sh}(\mathcal{C},K)$ and $\text{Sh}(\mathcal{C},J)$ the same in general?

As I say in the title, I would like to know if one can define sites as categories endowed with pretopologies instead of topologies, in the sense that the resulting toposes of sheaves do not become structurally different. If not then I would like to know what is lost.

Comment: Yes. That is the whole point of the definition of "induced Grothendieck topology".

Comment: Ok, thanks. So the sheaf theory only depends on the topology and not the pretopology. I haven't tried it yet, but is it a difficult fact to prove?

Comment: It depends on how you define "induced Grothendieck topology". One way is more or less trivial but doesn't tell you what the covering sieves are; the other way tells you what the covering sieves are but requires more checking.